# Use Ctrl as modifier on Worksheet_SelectionChange

Tags: vba, excel, modifier-key

I would like to open a form when a **locked** cell is clicked in a specific way (double click, key modifiers, etc).

If I use `Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick`, it will show a *warning* after closing the form, stating that the cell is locked (which is annoyting).

If I use `Worksheet_SelectionChange`, *no warning* will appear, but the form will appear *every time* a cell is selected (which is a bit much).

Is there anyway to use a modifier, like `Ctrl`, combined with `Worksheet_SelectionChange`, so that the user has to make an active choice to open the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set `Cancel = True` at the end of your `Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick` sub.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    MsgBox "test"
    Cancel = True
End Sub
```

Comment: If you want to use a modifier, you will have to use the API call `GetKeyState` . See [this site for sample](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/keytest.aspx).

Comment: The `Cancel = True` did the trick. Lovely simply solution, thank you very much.